# Can I run Bamboo deployment project on schedule to deploy specific release and not necessarily the latest only?

Tags: bamboo

I have a Bamboo build plan with a deployment project. Currently, the deployment happens manually and we can select the specific release version to be deployed on the server (using the dropdown field selection). Now, if I add the trigger (on schedule), I believe, it always picks up the latest release version. My requirement is to schedule the deployment project and do the deployment based on the specific release version which is required for the deployment & not necessarily be the latest one.

I tried to call the Bamboo using the REST API curl like below by passing the environmentid and versionid:-

curl -X POST 'http://localhost:8085/rest/api/latest/queue/deployment/?environmentId=1212417&versionId=1310721' -u admin:admin -H "Accepts: application/json"

(please assume, the versionId given as '1310721' is 'release-2'). When I executed the REST call, it did the deployment for this release-2 but when the scheduler executed the deployment project, it again took the latest release version which was 'release-3' and not 'release-2'.

Is there any way to tell the Bamboo, okay, this is the release version which needs to be deployed automatically during the on-scheduled deployment trigger. and if the value (release version) is not given let it pick the latest release version.

Cheers